# Skipping loop iteration after catch Javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach, promise, async-await

I am building an API which needs to make calls to another API (specifically, Quickbooks Online) in a loop. The calls are wrapped in a promise which resolves or rejects based on what is returned from Quickbooks. All works correctly, however, I would like to be able continue the loop after catching errors. Currently, an error is caught and logged to the database, but the loop stops and no further calls are made. I have tried "return" and "continue" in the catch block to no avail.

Example of the code:

```
// This is part of a larger loop. Needs to be async
await paymentInfo.forEach(async ln => {

        var payRef = ln.payment_ref
        var vendor = ln.vendor_id

        var finalPayment = await service.createPayment(args)
          .then(console.log("Payment created"))
          .catch((err) => { 

            // Log error to DB
            service.dbUpdate(err)
            .then(console.log("Error Logged to DB"))
            .catch(() => {})

            // Continue??
       })
      // Database update here with payment ID
})
```

Ultimately, after the catch I just want to continue to the next iteration of the loop. From what I can see there isn't a simple way to do this. Any advice welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You already use `async`/`await`, so no need to use `.then`. You can just use `await` and catch errors with regular `try`/`catch`, then the `continue` will also intuitively work if you would put it in a `for`. But it seems you need to process the loop iterations in parallel, so each iteration will be inside a function invocation, meaning you can just `return`.

The other issue here is that you don't handle the errors in your async function because it is not awaited. Instead you await the `forEach` which returns nothing.

The fix is to `map` your array to an array of promises (the result of executing the anonymous async functions) and then await all those promises at once using `Promise.all`.

```js
await Promise.all(paymentInfo.map(ln => (async () => {

        var payRef = ln.payment_ref
        var vendor = ln.vendor_id

        try {
            var finalPayment = await service.createPayment(args)
            console.log("Payment created")
        } catch (err) {
            // Log error to DB
            try {
                await service.dbUpdate(err)
                console.log("Error Logged to DB"))
            } catch (e) {}

           return
        }

       // Database update here with payment ID
})())
```

However it doesn't seem logical to me now that you need a `continue` here after all, if the only reason was that you wanted to react on the possibility that the payment was not created. In that case you'd simply use the payment value unconditionally, because if an error was thrown, it would skip the rest of the `try` block anyway!

```js
await Promise.all(paymentInfo.map((async ln => {

        var payRef = ln.payment_ref
        var vendor = ln.vendor_id

        try {
            var finalPayment = await service.createPayment(args)
            console.log("Payment created")

            // Database update here with payment ID
        } catch (err) {
            // Log error to DB
            try {
                await service.dbUpdate(err)
                console.log("Error Logged to DB"))
            } catch (e) {}
        }
})())
```

Comment: Hmm, I see what you're getting at. Have had a go at doing it this way. It now breaks out of this block and continues on however it still does not seem to attempt to resolve or reject all promises in the array, it stops after the first is rejected.

Comment: That's why you should build the error handling inside the async function like I did in my example. Then that function's promise will always be resolved. Alternatively you could look at `Promise.allSettled` but that's very new and may not be available for your environment yet.